# how to scheduling a python script to send email using windows task scheduler

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scheduled-tasks

I have a python script that scrapes a website and  I want to send the data by email every day at 7:00 AM when i run the script the email is send and the function work perfect, but when I tried to use **windows Task Scheduler** in order to automate the script it doesn't run.

## code:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from email.utils import formatdate



def scrap_website():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get("https://www.bayt.com/en/international/jobs/executive-chef-jobs/").content,
        "lxml"
    )

    links = []
    for a in soup.select("h2.m0.t-regular a"):
        if a['href'] not in links:
            links.append("https://www.bayt.com"+ a['href'])
    joineddd = []

    for link in links:
        s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "lxml")
        jobdesc=s.select_one("div[class='card-content is-spaced'] p")

        alldt = [dt.text for dt in s.select("div[class='card-content is-spaced'] dt")]
        dt_Job_location =              alldt[0]
        dt_Job_Company_Industry =      alldt[1]
        dt_Job_Company_Type =          alldt[2]
        if len(alldt[3])>0:
            dt_Job_Job_Role =              alldt[3]
        elif len(dt_Job_Employment_Type)>0:
            dt_Job_Employment_Type =       alldt[4]
                
        alldt.append("link")
        alldt.append("description")
        
        
        alldd = [dd.text for dd in s.select("div[class='card-content is-spaced'] dd")]
        dd_job_location =             alldd[0]
        dd_job_Company_Industry =     alldd[1]
        dd_job_Company_Type =         alldd[2]
        if len(alldd[3])>0:
            dd_job_Job_Role =             alldd[3]
        elif len(dd_job_Employment_Type)>0:
            dd_job_Employment_Type =      alldd[4]
        
        alldd.insert(0,link)
        alldd.insert(1,jobdesc)
        joineddd.append(alldd)    
        print("-" * 80) 
    
    convert_to_dataFrame(joineddd)
    send_email()


def convert_to_dataFrame(joineddd):
    df = pd.DataFrame(joineddd,columns=["link","description","location","Company_Industry","Company_Type","Job_Role","Employment_Type"])
    df_to_excel = df.to_excel(r"F:\\AIenv\web_scrapping\\jobDesc.xlsx", index = False, header=True)


'''send email '''
def send_email():
    today = date.today()
    file = 'F:\\AIenv\web_scrapping\\jobDesc.xlsx'
    username='xxxxxxx'
    password='xxxxxxx'
    send_from = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
    send_to = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    Cc = 'recipient'
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = send_to
    msg['Cc'] = Cc
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime = True)
    msg['Subject'] = 'Hello, This is a test mail {}'.format(today)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
    port = '587'
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
    part = MIMEBase('application','vnd.ms-excel')
    part.set_payload(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='jobs Description--{}'.format(today))
    msg.attach(part)
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login(username,password)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to.split(',') + msg['Cc'].split(','), msg.as_string())
    smtp.quit()
    print('Mail Sent')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scrap_website()
```

In the windows task scheduler:

I follow the steps and create a trigger in order to run the script.

## task scheduler :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2021-02-02T14:33:03.1578212</Date>
    <Author>DESKTOP-LPD1575\LT GM</Author>
    <URI>\job_desc scheduled email</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2021-03-02T07:30:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-422056822-2861570755-2809137930-1002</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>F:\AIenv\web_scrapping\job_desc_email.py</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: Could you please copy your configuration for task scheduler? Also Is there any windows event log of related task in Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: it did not appear in the windows event viewer

Comment: Could you please take a snapshot (image) of task scheduler configuration? Also you can check the link https://www.jcchouinard.com/python-automation-using-task-scheduler/ with your current settings? if not detect any related events in windows event log, may be you got some misconfiguration in task scheduler or Antivirus blocked that!

Comment: i did check the link but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem, in the Exec tag, you must add the full python path to the Command

**Current Code:**

```
 <Exec>
  <Command>F:\AIenv\web_scrapping\job_desc_email.py</Command>
</Exec>
```

**Recommend Code:**

*assume C:\python39\python.exe is path of your python*

> ```
> <Exec>
>   <Command>C:\\python39\\python.exe F:\\AIenv\\web_scrapping\\job_desc_email.py</Command>
> </Exec>
> ```

Because in Windows OSes, .py files are not associated to run with python.exe like Linux & Macs OS. So to run a python script your should use the following format command:

> {path-to-your-python.exe} {path-to-your-python-script}

Comment: can you take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043262/how-to-automate-python-scripts-with-task-scheduler-on-windows-10)