# how to Automate Python Scripts with Task Scheduler on windows 10

Tags: python, automation, scheduled-tasks

I have python script that **scrapes** website and send email  the script work perfect  now I want to automate this task using windows task scheduler on windows 10, for this I create a **.bat** file  and add the path of the executable file **.bat** to the **action tab** in the task scheduler and in the trigger i want it to run daily.

The problem is that when i finished the configuration of this task the program did not run by its own.

My Question is where is the error in my configuration?

## .bat file:

```
F:\AIenv\Scripts\python.exe "F:\AIenv\web_scrapping\job_desc_email.py" pause
```

task scheduler configuration :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: why python is in "F:\AIenv\Scripts\python.exe", you used python zip installer, didn't you? Anyway, did that bat script work?

Comment: Just run a cmd.exe (Windows +R --> cmd) --> paste the bat script & copy the output

Comment: its solved thank you for your help it was a problem in the function